# Overriding the way public libraries treat push notifications

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, netmera

I am building an app that uses push notification and decided to simplify work and go for a public library that sends the message, [Netmera](http://www.netmera.com).

However, once the notification is received I can't seam to read it. Is there a way to do it directly?

If not what class do I need to override to be able to handle the text of the sent notification.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the actual push message text in your activity, then try:

```
NetmeraPushService.getPushMessage();
```